# What are the pros/cons in using pd.Index vs df.loc

Tags: python, pandas

What is the difference between using `pd.Index` vs `df.loc`? Is it effectively the same thing?

```py
idx = pd.Index(('a', 'b'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [0, 5]})

print(df.loc[:, ('a', 'b')],)
print(df[idx])
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `loc` is the preferred method is [described in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). Using multiple slices can lead to a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
idx = ['a', 'b']
d = df[idx]
d.iloc[0,0] = 9
```

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

In contrast, using `loc` doesn't trigger the `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
idx = ['a', 'b']
d = df.loc[:,idx]
d.iloc[0,0] = 9
```

Of note, `loc` also enables you to pass a specific axis as parameter:

```
df.loc(axis=1)[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `loc` , you can do with index slice and columns slice or combine, however `pd.index` can only do for column slice

```
df.loc[[0]]
   a  b  c
0  0  2  0

df.loc[[0],['a','b']]
   a  b
0  0  2
```

IMO, `loc` is more flexible to using, and I will select `loc` which will more clear for the long run or check back stage.

Comment: With the dataframe ive been working with I have to work with groups of columns and perform various operations across all rows. So I created a _index.py module which I import as idx then I can just call the groups df[idx.my_group1] …

Comment: @JasonLeaver you can store them in a dict ~